filtering command output with awk
I want to extract the hostname (rd5044) from the output of a psql command like the below:
postgres@internal-rd5112:/opt/db/postgres/bin> psql -p 5434 -tc "SHOW primary_conninfo ;"
 user=replicator passfile='/home/postgres/.pgpass' channel_binding=prefer host='internal-rd5044.efa-bauen.portal.cn-mv.de' port=5434 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=0 sslsni=1 ssl_min
_protocol_version=TLSv1.2 gssencmode=disable krbsrvname=postgres target_session_attrs=any


So there is a trailing empty line plus masses of text around my target rd5044.
I'd start with | awk "NR==1" but would have no clue how to proceed from there.
someone suggested  | awk -F'[\'-]' '/host=/{print $(NF-1)}', but that does not run (as if there was a missing quote or so).
Can somebody help me out on this?

awk -F"['-]" '/host=/{print $(NF-3)}' file gives the following output: rd5044.efa

Please [edit] your question and show us the expected output. Do you want to subtract rd5044, so remove it from the output, or do you want to remove everything else and only keep rd5044? And how can we know which part you want to keep? Will it always be a subset of the value given for host=? Will the string host= always be there? And how can we know which part of internal-rd5044.efa-bauen.portal.cn-mv.de is the part you want? Will it always be the string between the first - and the first . in the host= value? Please [edit] your question and explain what you need more clearly.

I want to keep rd5044.

The command awk -F'[\47]' '/host=/{print $(NF-1)}' would output full hostname.

Please EDIT your question and answer the things we ask in comments. You said you want to keep rd5044. OK, so how can we find it? How can we know which part of this large input string you want to keep?

With awk, close to what you tried to achieve:
... | awk -F '[.-]' '/ host=/{print $(NF-7)}'


If the host='internal part is reliable:
With GNU grep:
... | grep -oP " host='internal-\K[^.]+"

With Perl:
... | perl -lne 'print $& if / host=\047internal-\K[^.]+/'

or
... | perl -lne 'print $1 if / host=\047internal-([^.]+)/'

Gives:
rd5044


tanks, great answer. For me its $(NF-7). not $(NF-6) in the awk variant though

Even simplified now.

fantastic ! actually the $NF-x depends on the postgres version a bit. an older one has a slightly different conent then then newer v14.

A cleaner solution would be to retrieve the complete hostname and post process it maybe.

If internal is consistent, better use my grep version

@vms if you have examples of different outputs/formats (eg, different posgres versions) then update the question to include such examples, along with the expected output for each example

According to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/17/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-PRIMARY-CONNINFO, that has a format of a connection string described at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/17/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING.
That can be either a:
postgresql://[userspec@][hostspec][/dbname][?paramspec]

Or a space separated list of of keyword = value with space optional around the = and value possibly quoted with single quotes and with \ and ' escaped within using \.
So example values could be:
comment='was host=\'foo\'' host=::1
postgresql://user:test123@[::1]:1234/asdasd
host=127.1
host = foo.bar
host='xn--internal-stphane-lqb.foo.info'

(by the way, the last one is the internal-stéphane.foo.info International Domain Name, converted to ASCII. Once you remove the .foo.info and internal- prefix, once encoded with IDNA, that becomes xn--stphane-cya).
Parsing the URI format can be done easily using perl's URI module as that scheme follows roughly the same syntax as the http scheme:
$ echo 'postgresql://user:test123@[::1]:1234/asdasd' |
   perl -MURI -lne 's/^postgresql/http/; print URI->new($_)->host'
::1

Extracting the keyword = value one can be done also relatively easily with perl regexps:
echo "comment='was host=\'foo\'' host=::1" |
   perl -l -0777 -pe '
     while (m{(?:^|\G\s)\s*([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*('\''(?:\\.|[^\\'\''])*'\''|[^\\'\''\s]+)}sg) {
       $field{$1} = $2;
     }
     $_ = $field{host};
     s/\\(.)/$1/gs;
     s/^'\''(.*)'\''\z/$1/s;'
::1

The IDNA decoding/encoding to be able to remove a internal- prefix from international domain names could be done with the Net::IDN::Encode module:
$ echo xn--internal-stphane-lqb.foo.info |
    perl -MNet::IDN::Encode=:all -lpe '
      $_ = domain_to_unicode($_);
      s/\..*//s;
      s/^internal-//;
      $_ = domain_to_ascii($_);'
xn--stphane-cya

Or to keep it in Unicode (output in UTF-8 if in a locale that uses UTF-8):
echo xn--internal-stphane-lqb.foo.info |
  perl -MNet::IDN::Encode=:all -C -lpe '
    $_ = domain_to_unicode($_);
    s/\..*//s;
    s/^internal-//'
stéphane

Of course, we wouldn't want to remove that \..* from IPv4 addresses. There are many ways to represent an IPv4 address. The most common is the quad-decimal one like 127.0.0.1, but that can also be written 127.1 or 0x7f000001 or 0x7f.0.0x1. Not stripping the "domain" if the hostname matches /^(?:\d+|0x[\da-f]+)\./i should be a relatively safe heuristic.
So, putting it all together, that could be:
psql -p 5434 -tc "SHOW primary_conninfo ;" |
  perl -MURI -MNet::IDN::Encode=:all -C -l -0777 -pe '
    if (m{^postgresql(://.*)}) {
      $_ = URI->new("http$1")->host;
    } else {
      while (m{(?:^|\G\s)\s*([^\s=]+)\s*=\s*('\''(?:\\.|[^\\'\''])*'\''|[^\\'\''\s]+)}sg) {
        $field{$1} = $2;
      }
      $_ = $field{host};
      s/\\(.)/$1/gs;
      s/^'\''(.*)'\''\z/$1/s;
    }
    $_ = domain_to_unicode($_);
    s/\..*//s unless /^(?:\d+|0x[\da-f]+)\./;
    s/^internal-//'

(add a $_ = domain_to_ascii($_) if you want it back in IDNA format instead of being left in Unicode).

Replace cat file below with whatever psql command produces the output in your question.
Given the input you show, you could just use sed for that, e.g. with GNU or BSD sed for -E:
$ cat file | sed -En "s/.* host='[^-]*+-([^-.]+).*/\1/p"
rd5044

or:
$ cat file | sed -En 's/.* host=\x27[^-]*+-([^-.]+).*/\1/p'
rd5044

or with any sed:
$ cat file | sed -n "s/.* host='[^-]*-\([^-.]*\).*/\1/p"
rd5044

If I wanted to use awk for that, though, then with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() I'd write:
$ cat file | awk 'match($0, / host=\047[^-]+-([^-.]+)/, a) { print a[1] }'
rd5044

or with any awk:
$ cat file | awk 'sub(/.* host=\047[^-]+-/,"") && sub(/\..*/,"")'
rd5044

Regarding why I use \x27 in sed but \047 in awk to match ', see Why are ASCII escape sequences for ' treated differently in grep/sed/awk?.
Regarding why awk -F'[\'-]' ... in the question doesn't work for the OP - you cannot escape ' within a '-delimited string in shell. That'd need to be awk -F'['\''-]' or awk -F"['-]" or awk -F'[\047-]'.
